# Magento 2 :Product Filter in magento 2

Tags: product, magento2.3, collection, filter

Please suggest any **free module** which can provide the ***filter in the product listing page*** like the below screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Manadev is the good option for layered navigation filter. 
https://marketplace.magento.com/extension-layered-navigation-filters-with-multiple-select.html